# Edit XLSM file with Google sheets (without converting files to GS)

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Excel files stored in Google Drive can now be edited with Google Sheet.
Any editing is saved directly to the Excel file (no conversion to GS and exporting required).

However, when setting up **script** to edit an Excel file stored in my Google Drive I have issues accessing the file. The following error appears:

*Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID 1J0CeedPvpj_eO--pFGhlBGWtfCBCZl1F. (line 6, file "Update forms")*

I have tried both openByUrl and openById functions, which return the same message.

```
var ssExcel = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J0CeedPvpj_eO--pFGhlBGWtfCBCZl1F/edit#gid=1411736235'),
sheetLISTES = ssExcel.getSheetByName('LISTES'),
sheetPRESENCE = ssExcel.getSheetByName('PRESENCE');
```

API drive v2 is enabled, I have an enterprise GSuite account.
The link to the shared file for Excel editing is the following:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q0wV1_TxhkQmIWTmc9PAq8JxW9ByGxcq/view?usp=sharing

Would there be any specific function to access Excel files in editing mode with a Google script?

I've already set scripts to convert Excel files to GS ones for editing by Google scripts and later saving as an xlsx, but this is not an option now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would say best bet is to [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) as the `xlsx` format is just not supported by Apps Script or the Sheets API natively.

Comment: @iansedano thank you for the feedback. Just got in touch with Google, who are reviewing the case.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Would there be any specific function to access Excel files in editing mode with a Google script?

No, however you could use a JavaScript library or `UrlFetchApp` to access an third party API that do that.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Thank you, Ruben. Are you aware of any publicly available API or library allowing for scripted Excel files editing?